# How to declare a boost recursive variant in mpl::list?

Tags: c++, boost-variant

How can I make this recursive variant work?  I'd like to have a container of variant, or container of container of variant.

```
template <class T>
class A 
{ 
    // ...
    T t_;
};

template <class T>
class AVariant
{
    typedef typename boost::make_variant_over<T>::type Type;
    Type t;

    // ...
};

template <class Container>
class Composite
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type T;
    Container container_of_any_;

    // ....
};
```

In main.cpp:

```
typedef AVariant<boost::mpl::list<
    A<int>,
    A<long>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<Composite<std::vector<Any> > > // Compile error: 'Any' is not declared in this scope
> > Any;
```

I understand that Compoiste > is not right, but not sure how?

Edit:
I've changed the following:

```
template <class T>
class AVariant
{
    typedef typename boost::make_recursive_variant_over<T>::type Type;
    Type t_;

    // ...

    template <class Archive>
    class SerializeVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
    {
        SerializeVisitor( Archive& ar ) : ar_(ar) {}
        template <typename U>
        void operator()( const U& t ) const
        {
            ar_ & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( t );
        }
    };

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize( Archive& ar, const unsigned int version )
    {
        boost::apply_visitor( SerializeVisitor<Archive>( ar ), t_ );
    }

};
```

Then instantiate using:

```
typedef AVariant<boost::mpl::list<
    A<double>,
    A<int>,
    std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> // to make the recursion slightly simplier
> > Any;
```

And my AVariant has a visitor to serialize as above.  It still gives compile error when serialization is invoked in main().  It seems to look for serialize() function for the class std::vector in the error:

```
const class std::vector<boost::variant<boost::detail::variant::recursive_flag<boost::detail::variant::over_sequence<boost::mpl::vector<A<double>, A<long int>, A, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_, std::allocator<boost::recursive_variant_> >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> > >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>, std::allocator<boost::variant<boost::detail::variant::recursive_flag<boost::detail::variant::over_sequence<boost::mpl::vector<A<double>, A<long int>, A, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_, std::allocator<boost::recursive_variant_> >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> > >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_> > >' has no member named 'serialize'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `boost::make_recursive_variant` instead of `boost::recursive_wrapper` with `boost::recursive_variant_` in it.So you should try this:

```
typedef AVariant<boost::mpl::list<
A<int>,
A<long>,
boost::make_recursive_variant<Composite<std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> > 
  >::type > > Any;
```

This can help you.

You should refer here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive.recursive-variant
and here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp for more information about recursive variants.
If you want to serialize variant you should better use `boost::variant` visitation mechanism to write out the actual type contained in the variant:

```
 variant_serializer ser;
 boost::apply_visitor( ser, your_variant);
```

Comment: thanks. What does boost::recursive_variant_ do?  It appears that's trying to put a placeholder to delay the type declaration.  When I try to serialize Any (A<>, AVariant<> and Composite all have serialize() functions), it gives me error: boost::make_recursive_variant<Composite<std::vector<mpl_::arg<1>, std::allocator<mpl_::arg<1> > > >, ... >' has no member named 'serialize'.

Comment: A<>, AVariant<> and Composite all have serialize() functions.  AVariant<> has serialize() visitor as well.  I've edited the original post to reflect those.  But compile still doesn't work.  it seems to look for serialize() function around the recursive variant.